# Expected position in random permutation

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-permutations

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ numbers, and $\pi(x):S\rightarrow \left\{ 1,\ldots,n\right\}$ define a permutation. The position $p(x, \pi)$ of an element $x \in S$ in a given permutation $\pi$ is the sum of all elements to the left of $x$ in that permutation, i.e $$p(x,\pi)=\sum_{y\in S:\pi\left(y\right)<\pi\left(x\right)}y$$.

I'm interested in the expected value of $p(x, \pi)$ for known $x, S$ and random $\pi$.

Trying with a few small examples, it seems this value is $E(p(x))=\frac{-x+\sum_{y \in S} y}{2}$.

Is this right? How can this be proven?

Comment: what does the upper index $\sum^S$ mean? If you sum up the elements of $S$, whose $\pi$-image is less than this of $x$, the expectation equals $\frac12 \sum (S\setminus \{x\})$, since each element of $S\setminus \{x\}$ is taken with probability 1/2.

Comment: Edited to clarify "position" formula and to fix my intuition which was incorrect. Your comment provides the answer, thank you very much!

Comment: It doesn't belong there (I was copying from my code which is a slightly different problem). Fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: Any number $y\neq x$ appears to the left of $x$ with probability $1/2$. And this question would look better at MSE.